# How can I assign shortcuts to "Auto Execution" and "Always" checkbox of animation nodes in node editor toolbar?

Tags: shortcut, animation-nodes

I need to assign shortcuts to "Auto execution" and "Always" checkbox to speed up my workflow. I tried to assign them myself but there is no add shortcut option to them, python code after hovering it, didn't helped me either. I tried to read some documentation, but only to fail.
Note: i am not a computer nerd.!
[Here is the screenshot for better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyGXU.png)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, one can't set a shortcut to toggle a checkbox. The only way to do that is to create an addon that register an operator that does the toggle and create a custom keymap for your shortcut as described [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_64_9/info_tutorial_addon.html#keymap).

Animation Nodes define the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to disable Auto Execution as described in the [documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/getting_started/interface.html#ctrl-shift-q).